# How do I Insert dash after every 4th character in input in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

My requirement is to take input for credit card number, which should automatically display a hyphen (-) after every 4th character. I could find examples for JQuery, python etc, but not for ADF.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a converter. You could start by using the `af:convertNumber` converter, if it doesn't suffice your requirements you can write your own.

More info about `af:convertNumber`  can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e12419/tagdoc/af_convertNumber.html).

More info about custom converters can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/adf/ADFUI/af_validate.htm#ADFUI360).